# Perspective transform for SVG path with Bezier curves

Tags: svg, geometry, css-transforms

I followed this thread here (unfortunately its very old, ancient I would say):
[Perspective transform of SVG paths (four corner distort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919398/perspective-transform-of-svg-paths-four-corner-distort)

And this thread contains great pdf explaining how calcuations are done (see below).

Question: **in the original post author says the approach will work for simple paths but not arcs. Can someone help me understand - would the approach work for Bezier curves?** The font used in the example obviously is using curves though...

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand about the CSS answer?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/28397315/1038015

Comment: Hey Robert (btw I learned A LOT thanks to you - thank you!:). CSS 3D transforms are not applicable at the SVG element level afaik. Hence I can't use those (although I checked this example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/10571478 and it is impressive). The problem I am trying to solve is ability to apply these 4 point distortions at a given SVG element level provided all of those are paths. Nuance is that my paths always use quadratic or cubic bezier...

Comment: CSS 3d transforms work in Firefox and as far as I know Chrome on SVG elements. There may of course be bugs.

Comment: I will try to  check that. For my goals I need to ensure transform: matrix3d(...) is what works. Will test and see.

Comment: Hmm ok so even though css did work for me in chrome i want to explore option where i obtain “new” coordinates from a script and then update my elements. Will do a pilot tonight and see how far i can go. CSS based solution wouldnt fit mostly cause i want to do arbitrary positions for the frame

Comment: I think You can convert [BEZIER to interpolation cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214), apply perspective on the control points and than convert back to BEZIER and use that in your SVG. The result however could a bit differ from real perspective applied to your original BEZIER. To improve accuracy you can resample your BEZIER to more BEZIER patches ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can apply **affine** transformations to the control points of Bezier curve and get transformed Bezier curve.

But **perspective** transformations **are not applicable** to "usual" (used in fonts) Bezier curves - they produce **rational** Bezier curves.

Comment: I see, so if I will use approach in this example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/10591444 - it will not work for paths that contain Bezier correct?

Comment: This example calculates matrix of persp. transformation.Thus transfromation transforms  points to points and straight line segments to straight line segments. But if you apply it to control points of Bezier curve, resulting control points will describe another curve  - if you transform intermediate points of curve (as points), they will differ from corresponding points of transformed Bezier. I think that result would be quite close for small perspective distortions, but for strong distortions curve could essentially deviate.

Comment: There's no way to convert (or approximate) a rational Bezier curve coming from a perspective transformation into a 'classic' Bezier curve?

Comment: @Claudio Exact transformation is not possible, approximation with some tolerance should be real  - having two inner points of rational curve (say for t=1/3 and 2/3), one can make classic Bezier with same points at the same t.  If approximation is bad,  perhaps it is worth to divide rational curve into smaller pieces)